# Pandas to open JSON File as DataFrame : ValueError: Expected object or value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

My JSON File Looks Like

```
{"Article":{"161":"Iran jails blogger for 14 years\n\nAn ........"},"Preprocessed-Article":{"161":"Iran jails blogger 14.........."},"Vector":{"161":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0......]}}
```

I am trying to open it using

```
df = pd.read_json(r'/content/NewsArticles.json',lines = False)
print(df.head())
```

to read the file. But am getting

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1117         if orient == "columns":
   1118             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1119                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1120             )
   1121         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Please Help.

Comment: Maybe you should provide the full JSON content, or it's hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file may be corrupt.  If I modify your JSON example as below by completing the quotations around the strings and getting rid of ellipsis, your code works fine:

```
{"Article":{"161":"Iran jails blogger for 14 years\n\nAn ........"},
"Preprocessed-Article":{"161":"Iran jails blogger 14.........."},
"Vector":{"161":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}}
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, originally it already has those quotes. I just missed them while typing in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is not format as expected. Try resolving it and it should work.

```
{
  "Article": {
    "161": "Iran jails blogger for 14 years\n\nAn ........}",
    "Preprocessed-Article": {
      "161": "Iranjailsblogger14.........."
    },
    "Vector": {
      "161": [
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, The quotes are correctly placed in the file. I have updated the data again

Comment: Under the vector["json"] object there is a value **0.0......**, which isn't a number. I see that isn't changed till now.